# Broken link on SO Careers support page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, blog, broken-link

Go to SO Careers 'Support' page: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/support

Then, click on the '[How to Write a Great Developer Job Listing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/how-to-write-a-great-developer-job-listing/)' link under the '**More Information**' section.

The link currently points to: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/how-to-write-a-great-developer-job-listing/

> [image]

Upon doing Google search I found: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/resources/great-job-listing

I believe this is a correct link.

Comment: Sometimes old posts vanish from the blog (something to do with corrupted build, not sure about the technical details). In the past it took long hours to fix, now looks like it was faster. Anyway, all posts are back to the blog now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our blog build picked up incorrect configuration which limited the number of posts on the blog and in turn caused the broken link [How to Write a Great Developer Job Listing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/how-to-write-a-great-developer-job-listing/). It is all fixed now.

Thanks for the report! :)