# Blog sometimes losing pages due to picking up incorrect configuration

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, 404-not-found

As SE developer Chris explains in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267552/broken-link-to-our-advice-on-writing-great-tag-wikis?noredirect=1#comment867752_267552):

> We use a Jekyll-based blog generation system. Unfortunately, sometimes some of the pages do not generate correctly, thus causing the files to be missing. Regenerating the blog usually solves this, but knowing when we have a "busted blog build" is half the battle. (The other half of the battle is fixing the system for good so that all pages generate correctly all the time.)

This happens quite often, think the first time was reported as [Where's the Strangedupe blog post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262077/wheres-the-strangedupe-blog-post).

All past reports are about single missing page, hence starting now a "generic" report.

I am aware the battle is long and hard, would be happy to get updates about the progress right here in this report. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be resolved now. Our blog builds are based on https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll which apparently has an out of date version of the mercenary gem that will intermittently ["parse the completely wrong options"](https://github.com/jekyll/mercenary/pull/35) and cause the build to use the wrong config file.

I upgraded that gem from 0.3.3 to 0.3.5 on our build servers, which should fix the problem. I have also added a check to fail the build if the generated post count is lower than expected.

Comment: I think a dev said this before and still it happened again today, but guess only time will tell. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Balpha found the root cause last month and posted http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266359/142481 but no changes were made since it landed on my todo list behind a bunch of other projects. I was pinged about it again today and found my grease gun so the squeaky wheel should be fixed now :)

Comment: @GregBray but I thought Balpha said it was fixed in 0.3.4 and today I posted a [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267544/254554)

Comment: @HackerKarma it was fixed in 0.3.4 of the Mercenary gem, but we were still using 0.3.3. Now we are using 0.3.5 and have a check to fail any builds  with low post counts

Comment: @GregBray Indeed... Just re-read Balpha's post and noticed that... Thanks for the gem update.

Comment: Awesome! Expect a nice boon soon...